# Why do I get the error message that my cursor is invalid?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
DECLARE
v_deptno empcopy.deptno%TYPE;
v_empno empcopy.empno%TYPE;
v_sal empcopy.sal%TYPE;
v_bonus NUMBER(7,2);
CURSOR emp_cursor IS
SELECT deptno, empno, sal
FROM empcopy
WHERE v_deptno < 25;
BEGIN
FETCH emp_cursor INTO v_deptno, v_empno, v_sal;
FOR r_emp in emp_cursor LOOP
IF v_sal < 3000 THEN
v_bonus := v_sal * 1.1;
ELSE
v_bonus := v_sal * 1.12;
v_deptno := v_deptno;
v_empno := v_empno;
v_sal := v_sal;
END IF;
INSERT INTO emp3
VALUES(v_empno, v_deptno, v_sal);
FETCH emp_cursor INTO v_deptno, v_empno, v_sal;
END LOOP;
CLOSE emp_cursor;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_deptno || v_empno || v_bonus);

END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SET VERIFY ON
```

---

```
SQL> @ emp3
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at line 11
```

I was wondering why it says I have an invalid cursor. I have tried to change the name of the value that has to be < 25 but it didn't work.

Comment: Please don't completely re-edit your question with a new title and a new piece of code after people have answered your original problem. You are just making this thread confusing for everybody else. If you have a new problem please **ask a new question**. By all means link to the original question if you think it's pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

Code you wrote is full of errors (you already know that), I don't know whether I'll catch them all, but I'll try:

- cursor selects data whose `v_deptno < 25`. But, `v_deptno` looks like a locally declared variable (the first one you declared), so - unless there's a column whose name is `v_deptno`, it'll fail.

  - besides, hardcoding `deptno` value to "`25`" doesn't scale at all. I'd suggest you to switch to a stored procedure which accepts department number as a parameter
- the first executable line is `FETCH`, but it should have been `OPEN` (if you choose to do everything

  - manually:

    - declare a cursor
    - declare cursor variable (or separate variables, as you did)
    - open the cursor
    - loop
    - fetch from the cursor
    - exit when cursor%notfound
    - do *something*
    - end loop
    - close cursor
  - or, better, using cursor `FOR` loop where Oracle does all the *dirty* job for you:

    - `FOR` cursor in (`SELECT` statement) `LOOP`
    - do *something*
    - end loop
- when you're checking salary (in `IF`), `ELSE` is ... more than strange. What's the purpose of `v_deptno := v_deptno;` (as well as other 3 variables you set to what they were)?
- `INSERT` statement: it lacks column list you're inserting into. This is not an error (might fail if you did it wrong), but - it is confusing, especially when there are many columns involved).

  - but, you're inserting `V_SAL`. OK. Why did you compute `V_BONUS`, then? You never, ever used it (except in `DBMS_OUTPUT`, but that just displays the value, never does anything with it as far as data in the database is concerned)

---

OK, now my attempt, if I may.

First, code you wrote, fixed (I'm inserting `V_BONUS` value):

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_bonus number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select deptno, empno, sal
  5                  from empcopy
  6                  where deptno < 25
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      if cur_r.sal < 3000 then
 10         v_bonus := cur_r.sal * 1.1;
 11      else
 12         v_bonus := cur_r.sal * 1.12;
 13      end if;
 14
 15      insert into emp3 (empno, deptno, sal)
 16        values (cur_r.empno, cur_r.deptno, v_bonus);
 17    end loop;
 18  end;
 19  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From emp3;

     EMPNO     DEPTNO        SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369         20       1100
      7566         20     3272,5
      7782         10       2695
      7788         20       3360
      7839         10       5600
      7876         20       1210
      7902         20       3360
      7934         10       1430

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

However, that can be done with a single `INSERT` statement at the SQL layer, you don't need PL/SQL at all. So, unless you're just practicing your PL/SQL skills, I'd suggest you to use this option:

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> insert into emp3 (empno, deptno, sal)
  2    select empno,
  3           deptno,
  4           case when sal < 3000 then sal * 1.1
  5                else sal * 1.12
  6           end
  7    from empcopy
  8    where deptno < 25;

8 rows created.

SQL> select * From emp3;

     EMPNO     DEPTNO        SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369         20       1100
      7566         20     3272,5
      7782         10       2695
      7788         20       3360
      7839         10       5600
      7876         20       1210
      7902         20       3360
      7934         10       1430

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Finally, a stored procedure option I suggested at the beginning; instead of `<` in the `where` clause, use `=`.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_bonus (par_deptno in empcopy.deptno%type)
  2  is
  3    v_bonus number;
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select deptno, empno, sal
  6                  from empcopy
  7                  where deptno = par_deptno    --> "=" instead of "<"
  8                 )
  9    loop
 10      if cur_r.sal < 3000 then
 11         v_bonus := cur_r.sal * 1.1;
 12      else
 13         v_bonus := cur_r.sal * 1.12;
 14      end if;
 15
 16      insert into emp3 (empno, deptno, sal)
 17        values (cur_r.empno, cur_r.deptno, v_bonus);
 18    end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    p_bonus (par_deptno => 25);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

The table `EMP3` apparently has fewer columns than the `INSERT` command provides data for (4).

Check the definition of that `EMP3` table and make sure the table and the insert command can be matched.

After the comments/discussion, this is the code is a more readable form (I added indentation):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
DECLARE
    v_deptno empcopy.deptno%TYPE;
    v_empno empcopy.empno%TYPE;
    v_sal empcopy.sal%TYPE;
    v_bonus NUMBER(7,2);

    CURSOR emp_cursor IS
        SELECT deptno, empno, sal
        FROM empcopy
        WHERE v_deptno < 25;
BEGIN
    FETCH emp_cursor INTO v_deptno, v_empno, v_sal;

    FOR r_emp in emp_cursor LOOP

        IF v_sal < 3000 THEN
            v_bonus := v_sal * 1.1;
        ELSE
            v_bonus := v_sal * 1.12;
            v_deptno := v_deptno;
            v_empno := v_empno;
            v_sal := v_sal;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO emp3
            VALUES(v_empno, v_deptno, v_sal);

        FETCH emp_cursor INTO v_deptno, v_empno, v_sal;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE emp_cursor;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_deptno || v_empno || v_bonus);

END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SET VERIFY ON
```

What this code *appears* to be doing is:

- go over every "employee" record in table `EMPCOPY`
- for each of those records, check if the `salary` is lower than *3000* and calculate the bonus by multiplying `salary` by `1.1` if it is
- if the `salary` is not lower than *3000*, `v_bonus` is calculated by `1.12`
- after this, the new values should be `INSERT`ed into table `EMP3`
- finally, the values of the very last inserted record are printed out.

First off: the poor folks that make less than 3000 also only get 110% bonus while the already better off employees get 2% more on top? 
I'm aware that this is common practice, but I'd advocate aiming for a better, fairer world - at least in simple coding examples like this.

Now to the code.
What this code should do, does not require the use of cursors at all. In fact, it is not a good practice in this case.

Instead, just use plain SQL to achieve the desired effect:

```
INSERT INTO EMP3 
    (empno, deptno, sal, bonus)
    (SELECT 
        empno, deptno, sal
        , case 
            when sal < 3000 then sal * 1.1
            else sal * 1.12
          end as bonus 
     FROM 
        empcopy
     WHERE 
        deptno < 25);
```

The caveat here is that the target table `EMPCOPY` needs to have a column for `BONUS`. That this column is missing was likely the cause for the original issue.

Also worth noting that this approach does not print out anything.
If that is a requirement for the solution, then this should be done after the INSERT (a simple FOR LOOP over the target table should do).

I hope that helps.

Comment: after correcting that not it says ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06511: PL/SQL: cursor already open
ORA-06512: at line 7
ORA-06512: at line 13

Comment: The cursor is open after the OPEN CURSOR command. By using FOR ... IN <CURSOR> the code tries to open it again. It’s either OPEN CURSOR or FOR IN CURSOR. Alternatively, the code could first OPEN CURSOR ... END CURSOR and then FOR IN CURSOR.... But realistically, it’s probably easiest to just use FOR ... IN CURSOR and not worry about opening/closing cursors manually.

Comment: I fixed that problem and of course another one came up SQL> @ emp3
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at line 11

Comment: Can you add/update the question with your current code? I think the original question has been answered BTW.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the beginning but it must have a for loop cursor and it must only take in the employees that have a deptno less than 25